# Where can I find a dataset of company office addresses?

Tags: business, companies, address, location

For an application I'm building, I need to find a list of all office addresses for large companies (e.g. the addresses for each of Google's 170+ offices, not just their headquarters).

The closest solution I've found is https://craft.co/, although that seems to be an API for large enterprises.

(happy to write code to scrape the data, or pay for the data, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

https://opencorporates.com/ provides access to data on 200M+ companies in many jurisdictions across the planet

OpenCorporates labels itself as "open data" but the reality is more nuanced:

> API keys are available in two ways: free of charge to anyone legitimately working on a project that will contribute back to the open-data community (“share-alike API keys”), and for a fee under our non-share-alike API terms (“non-share-alike API keys”), for example for use in commercial or proprietary applications.

I have not found a link at which the whole database can be downloaded, so it does not qualify as "open data". However, it says:

> The OpenCorporates database is licensed under the Open Database License.

Source: https://opencorporates.com/legal/licence

Comment: https://opencorporates.com/info/our-data/

Comment: That doesn't seem to have office address information for companies, other than their singular headquarters

Comment: Link-only answers are not ideal, as links tend to break. I edit your answer to show how to include the most relevant excerpts. Cheers!

Comment: it's not open, they have an intentionally misleading name.